# Is there an official gapi library for browsers?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-api, google-api-js-client

I'm currently using the "google api" in a web application by referencing the script "https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js". However, I'm using it in a "angular4" application that I'm bundling with "webpack" and I would like to install and bundle the gapi package as well. However, I didn't seem to find an official package for this.

I found [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis), however, it does not seem to be targetted for browsers.
I also find [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gapi-client) but it does not seem very official.

Comment: Gapi is the Google apis js client.   I am not a web dev so really cant help with packages and the like but if it exists its probably on one of these pages https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client  https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/

Comment: Thanks, I will try these and come back to you.

Comment: Like i said i cant be much help.  I tweaked your tags you should get some attention from web devs now.    Someone should know.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean Offical. Actually Google doesn't make api samples

There is a Samples github ibrary for Google apis

The sample codes present in them are contributed by some Developers